# в библиотеке g4f бот не сохраняет память

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x, python-openai, chatgpt-api

Пишу бота на Aiogram с g4f, у меня есть полностью готовый код, но почему-то у ботов не сохраняется память, вот часть кода в которой не работает память:

```
            if message.from_user.id not in gpt4_user_list:
                response = await g4f.ChatCompletion.create_async(
                    model=g4f.models.gpt_4,
                    messages=message_list[message.from_user.id],
                    provider=g4f.Provider.GeekGpt,
                )
            if message.from_user.id in gpt4_user_list:
                response = await g4f.ChatCompletion.create_async(
                    model=g4f.models.gpt_35_turbo,
                    messages=message_list[message.from_user.id],
                    provider=g4f.Provider.ChatBase,
                )
```

Возможно это проблема в провайдерах (provider), но не думаю.